# PayUBiz hash integration failed-iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, payumoney, payu

I am calculating hash from server and passed it to `payUbiz` hash object. When hash value passed to hash object of `payUbiz` it binds as `optional` value i.e. `Optional(*hashValue*)`. I have tried to convert optional string to string, but it won't worked. It gives `Invalid Parameter` error.
Below is my hash value response from server:

```
{
    errorMessage = "Success.";
    lastSyncDateTime = "<null>";
    result = {
              furl = "http://192.168.3.2:93/PayU/AppointmentResponse";
              hash = 4875a6096814ee1fbe19110582ea0a1564f81880ae66539b94384d3d332106855a00132332919724f085d02d64cffb6d47ff98f3ac4eb7d5e2bb31b4022e3f06;
              merchantKey = gtKFFx;
              mobileSDKHASH = 110f85b862578214e5c38637762a6fce9c34bd5e2d78bc34a486f0ee2e3e5d0fada221795de4b67952ec2cff6b4d0fe8877506e7a5480bbdbfdf9045521d8523;
              payURequestArea = 1;
              profileID = 7;
              surl = "http://192.168.3.2:93/PayU/AppointmentResponse";
              txnID = 62604613a06163c02ddd;
              userID = 18;
              vasMobileSDKHASH = 7da0f4fef5bab0e5034f37f9503bdcbede00cc2cd0cf6cbb4e43baa9d57f05680305885199e2b0d38e8cf12895fd06f4d3dd3fb422535feeb555adc58e2cf3cc;
             };
    statusCode = 200;
}
```

This is `hashvalue` printed from `payUbiz`

```
paymentHash: Optional("4875a6096814ee1fbe19110582ea0a1564f81880ae66539b94384d3d332106855a00132332919724f085d02d64cffb6d47ff98f3ac4eb7d5e2bb31b4022e3f06")

vasForMobileSDKHash: Optional("7da0f4fef5bab0e5034f37f9503bdcbede00cc2cd0cf6cbb4e43baa9d57f05680305885199e2b0d38e8cf12895fd06f4d3dd3fb422535feeb555adc58e2cf3cc")

paymentRelatedDetailsHash: Optional("110f85b862578214e5c38637762a6fce9c34bd5e2d78bc34a486f0ee2e3e5d0fada221795de4b67952ec2cff6b4d0fe8877506e7a5480bbdbfdf9045521d8523")
```

**Please give solution on this**

Comment: Here you print optionvalue. you need to set String replace with ? to !.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced same issue a month ago. I think `Optional` value is not cause of issue. The response itself say's that **"Invalid Parameters"** means there are some invalid parameters passed to Payment gateway.

Please check following parameters are provided or not:

```
    paymentParam.key = *Your key*;

    paymentParam.transactionID = *Transaction ID*
    paymentParam.amount = *Amount*
    paymentParam.productInfo = *Product Info*;
    paymentParam.surl = *Success URL*;
    paymentParam.furl = *Failure URL*;
    paymentParam.firstName = "";
    paymentParam.email = "";
    paymentParam.udf1 = "";
    paymentParam.udf2 = "";
    paymentParam.udf3 = "";
    paymentParam.udf4 = "";
    paymentParam.udf5 = "";        
    paymentParam.hashes = hashes;  //**Important**
    paymentParam.userCredentials = "default";  **//This was the issue in my case, i have accidentally deleted this parameter**
    // ENVIRONMENT_TEST for test environment:
    paymentParam.environment = ENVIRONMENT_TEST;        
    // Set this property if you want to give offer:
    paymentParam.offerKey = "";
```

> Please check for **paymentParam.userCredentials = "default"** parameter,
>   because after adding this parameter i have solved my issue.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks its Works for me.